# using implode inside insert query

Tags: mysql, database, insert, implode

How can I use implode inside query to insert the values into db. here is my example:

Html form :

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
address:<input type="text" name="address" /><br />
phone:<input type="text" name="phone" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" />
</form>
```

I use this code to get _POST values from the application form:

```
$x =  array_values($_POST);
```

and here to put "," comma between the strings so I can use it in the query :

```
$x =  "'".implode("','",$x)."'";
```

here is what I did:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbtable (name, address, phone) 
                       VALUES
                      ($x)");
```

When I echo $x:
the results is: 'name','address','phone','insert'

the code print "insert"<- it's the submit button. I think this is the problem

can anyone help me to fix my mistake please
Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you checked your error log? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this?

Comment: no error, but no insert :) thanks

Comment: If you echo the query and run it in PHPMyAdmin, does it run?

Comment: If I insert it directly in phpmyadmin it will inserted. so no error in the db

Comment: just echo $x and you'll know... if the echo is correct, echo mysql_error

Comment: when I echo $x, here is the results : 'name','address','phone','insert'

Comment: Hmmm, how can I remove the button value. I think the problem from it

Answer (score 0):

the implode shuld be like:

```
$x =implode("','",$x)."'";
```